# How do you write a regex string that drops .0 only when it is at the end of a string?

Tags: android, regex, google-bigquery

Basically what I'm looking for is a regex string that gets everything before either .0 or .0.0 when either of those are the end of the string. If the string has .0 in the middle but ends with something else, it should stay as it is.

Android 7.0.0 should just be Android 7.
Android 6.0 should just be Android 6
Android 6.0.1 should stay as it is

I am using the regex dialect featured in google bigquery. The closest I have come is the regex pattern .*[^(.0|.0.0)] . I imagine the $ symbol should be in the pattern but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `"(?:\\.0)+$"` / `(?:\.0)+$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?:\.0)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t9WRxL/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5C.0)%2B%24):

[image]

*Details*:

- `(?:\.0)+` - zero or more occurrences of a dot and a zero
- `$` - end of string.